# Integrating Apache Solr custom plugin with WordNet

Tags: java, solr, jar, wordnet

I'm developing a very simple custom `SearchComponent` for Apache Solr that has to find synonyms of the query terms and return them in addition to the documents found. In order to get the synonyms, I'm using [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) and its JWNL Java API.

I created a project in Eclipse with the code suggested in the JWNL tutorial to start up the dictionary:

```
    try {
        JWNL.initialize(new FileInputStream("properties.xml"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JWNLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final Dictionary dictionary = Dictionary.getInstance();
```

The file `properties.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jwnl_properties language="en">
  <version publisher="Princeton" number="3.1" language="en"/>
  <dictionary class="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary">
    <param name="dictionary_element_factory" 
      value="net.didion.jwnl.princeton.data.PrincetonWN17FileDictionaryElementFactory"/>
    <param name="file_manager" value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl">
      <param name="file_type" value="net.didion.jwnl.princeton.file.PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile"/>
      <param name="dictionary_path" value="/path/dict"/>
    </param>
  </dictionary>
  <resource class="PrincetonResource"/>
</jwnl_properties>
```

It all works fine in Eclipse. It also works if I export the project with all the required libraries (Solr and JWNL) to a JAR file and run it from terminal, in another location, with `java -jar`.

But if I put the JAR in the `lib` folder of my Solr Core in order to implement the plugin (after having correctly registered it in the `solrconfig.xml` file) and try to run a simple query, this error appears in the response:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat sir.WordNetExpansionSearchComponent.process(WordNetExpansionSearchComponent.java:86)
```

which refers to this line of code:

```
indexWordN = dictionary.getIndexWord(POS.NOUN, term);
```

I tried to check and it appears that `dictionary` is set to null, despite the initialization. How is it possible? How can I fix it?

**EDIT 1:**

Here's the snippet from my `solrconfig.xml` where I register the plugin:

```
  <!-- WordNet Query Expansion Search Component -->

  <searchComponent class="sir.WordNetExpansionSearchComponent" name="wordnetExpansionSearchComponent">
  </searchComponent>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the WordNet Query Expansion component -->
  <requestHandler name="/expand" class="solr.SearchHandler">
      <arr name="last-components">
          <str>wordnetExpansionSearchComponent</str>
      </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Comment: could you show how you register plugin in the solrconfig.xml?

Comment: @Mysterion Sure, I added it in the original post